# nail pop in bathroom ceiling

Tags: bathroom, drywall, ceiling

Should I be concerned about this nail pop. I live in an apartment so I can’t really do much to the ceiling. Is it just a cosmetic thing? Is my safety at risk? Will it cause water leaks? Please help[image]

Comment: Got any... White out? Chalk? Paper spit ball....

Comment: With nails, it's only a question of *when* they will pop.

Answer (score 10):

Just one nail is not a safety risk. There drywall is not supposed to be a barrier to water infiltration, so this popped nail will not risk water getting in. Watch out if you see water stains on the ceiling, or nearby nails popping. That means that water is getting in the drywall, where it should not be. Then call your landlord.

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to call the landlord/maintenance crew _now_. At a minimum, it gets it on the record for when you've noticed it and that you've taken appropriate action. This way, they can't come back late claiming "you should have told us sooner, we're going to charge you for the repair!".